# Mysql Unable to make a query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to put some data in to my MySQL table using PHP. I'm already retrieving some data into a variable from the database. Let us say it is:

```
$data = "Some variable";
```

But the problem is that in the place of 
`Some variable` I have data like this

```
$data = $row['some data'];
```

I don't know what I am fetching may be some time it may be hyper links may be some time it may be just some junk data. Problem arises when I try to put  data into MySQL table.

I tried to echo out the query suppose this is the query

```
$query = "INSERT into table VALUES(0, '$data')";
```

The output was:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES(0,'Donatted book:'25 ways to improve life');
```

Here there is an upper quotation after donated book. But I can't change it because the data comes over here is from another database. How do I make this insert command work.

Here is how my code is working

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT*from table WHERE id=$content_id";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
    $data = $row['col'];

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO table VALUES(0, $data)";
    mysqli_query($query2);
?>
```

Comment: Code is not requerd my proble is specefic and @fred how to escape the data?.

Comment: I don't understand, $data is a string or an array ? Just look to mysql_real_escape_string() function.

Comment: @geekishfellow *Code is not requerd* YES it is required, since it depends on which MYSQL API you use!

Comment: @VincentDecaux it is a string

Comment: @geekishfellow, I would strongly suggest that if you want people's help, you give them the information they ask for. Remember we are under no obligation to assist you.

Comment: i am using mysqli_query();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `mysqli_*` API as mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29871478/mysql-unable-to-make-a-query#comment47868018_29871478).

You are looking for: [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

But even easier would be to use [`mysqli_* prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

**Side notes:**

`table` is a [MYSQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html), so you have to put backticks around it e.g.

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO `table` VALUES(0, $data)";
                     //^     ^
```

Also you're missing `$dbc` as first argument in your second query, so add it like this:

```
$row = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
```

I would also recommend you to check for errors with `or die(mysqli_error($db));`, e.g.

```
$row = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Comment: $query2="INSERT INTO table VALUES(0,mysqli_real_escape_string($data)) Is it possible to use like this?.

Comment: @geekishfellow If you concatenate it right it would be possible, but I wouldn't recommend it, since if you have multiple values it will get very unreadable! So just use it before your SQL string e.g. `$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $data);` (BTW: `$row=mysqli_query($query2);` You are missing the `$dbc` as first argument)

Comment: @geekishfellow May I know, why you unaccepted my answer? Something wrong with it?

Comment: I have used your answer but the answer which i accepted now is seems like a better answer and useful

Comment: @geekishfellow It's your decision, but the other answer doesn't address all problems from your code! And has errors in it!

Comment: I have accepted your answer and up voted the other one.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

```php
$dbtype = "mysql";
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "database_name";
$dbuser = "username";
$dbpass = "password";

// Create PDO connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);

// Perform INSERT statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (:value1, :value2)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);

// This values are escaped by PDO
$q->execute([':value1' => $data['some_data_1'], ':value2' => $data['some_data_2']));
```

Comment: *You should use* Maybe OP already uses PDO. You don't know what he's using since he doesn't show us his code

Comment: And there we have it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29871478/mysql-unable-to-make-a-query#comment47868018_29871478 He's using `mysqli_*` API! And not PDO.

Comment: @Rizier123 I was just trying to show him/her some good practices. That's all.